# Multiple texts to array

Tags: c#

I need to select multiple texts and put them into an array, but I get this error:

> **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'**

```
public static List<string> uploadFileList = new List<string>();

public void SelectFiles()
{
     int i;

     SelectedFileText.Text = "";

     dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

     dlg.Multiselect = true;

     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         foreach (String filename in dlg.FileNames)
         {
             SelectedFileText.Text += filename + "\n";
             SelectedFileText.Text = uploadFileList[i];
         }
     }     
}
```

Comment: Get rid of *magic value* `10` in `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` and put it as `i < uploadFileList.Count()`

Comment: @SlavenTojić IMHO, this is not a duplicate. This question shows lack of understanding of a few things, so simply solving the `IndexOutOfRangeException` will not answer this question.

Comment: Where do you set your `uploadFileList`? If this is your only code, it would be an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

when `uploadFileList` is empty, attempts to access non-existing element by index (`uploadFileList[i]`) result in an exception.

you can use List.AddRange and String.Join methods to avoid `for` loop completely

```
public void SelectFiles()
{   
     dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

     dlg.Multiselect = true;

     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

     if (result == true)
     {
         uploadFileList.Clear();
         uploadFileList.AddRange(dlg.FileNames);
         SelectedFileText.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, uploadFileList);   
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `List<T>` is **not** an array, and the code you've shared does not try to insert anything to the list, it tries to get values from that list.
You are getting this error because your list is empty, yet you try to extract values from it.

You should probably change the second line in the `foreach` loop to `uploadFileList.Add(filename)`, and get rid of the outer loop:

```
public void SelectFiles()
{
     int i;

     SelectedFileText.Text = "";

     dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

     dlg.Multiselect = true;

     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

     foreach (String filename in dlg.FileNames)
     {
         SelectedFileText.Text += filename + "\n";
         uploadFileList.Add(filename);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the two lines of

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

and

```
SelectedFileText.Text = uploadFileList[i];
```

The first assumes that there are ten items in the list which is accessed in the second statement.

If the list `uploadFileList` is populated elsewhere, I would suggest putting
`uploadFileList.Count()` in place of the first statement to only loop as many times as there are items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 10 items in your collection `uploadFileList`. Try looping through the collection until the end:

```
for (i = 0; i < uploadFileList.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (String filename in dlg.FileNames)
    {
        SelectedFileText.Text += filename + "\n";
        SelectedFileText.Text = uploadFileList[i];
    }
}
```

Or you can use foreach:

```
foreach (String file in uploadFileList)
{
    foreach (String filename in dlg.FileNames)
    {
        SelectedFileText.Text += filename + "\n";
        SelectedFileText.Text = file;
    }
}
```